# How do I extract code into a static method in Eclipse, passing fields as parameters?

Tags: java, eclipse, refactoring, indirection

Given this simplified scenario:

```
private String name;

private String getString() {
    return "Hello, " + name + "!";
}
```

I would like to capitalize the name with a `private static capitalize(String)` method. If I extract `name` into a method (CTRL-2 + M), then I get a `private String capitalize()` method that references the `name` field.

Here's the desired result: (before implementing capitalization)

```
private static String capitalize(String name) {
    return name;
}
```

I really want `capitalize` to be static, because I can then move it to some other class (SHIFT-ALT-V). Also, when there are multiple fields, moving them to parameters is tedious.

Is there any way to extract a method, or introduce an indirection that passes fields as parameters? It does not need to be a single refactoring; a combination might still save typing and human error.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sequence that would work:

1. Extract the field reference `name` to a new local variable (`Alt-Shift-L`), call it "toCap"
2. Extract a method from the reference to `toCap`, call it "capitalize"
3. Add modifier `static` to `capitalize`
4. Inline the extra local variable `toCap` (`Alt-Shift-I`).

Now you can move `capitalize` to the place of your liking.

For this exact scenario, it may not be worth it (simpler to directly create the static capitalize method), but I can see that in more complex situations this sequence of refactorings could actually help.

The general pattern behind this sequence is: before extracting a method, prepare all the arguments you want to pass into the method using fresh local variables. When the method has been extracted, inline the unwanted local variables.

Comment: This is a great answer. However, it does not address the need to extract a method that refers to more than one field. (note the use of plural in the final question) But thanks!

Comment: No problem, see the plural in the last paragraph of the answer :)

Comment: Ah, true! Ok, this works. Not the most convenient when there are many fields, but it works. I'll propose something possibly faster.

Answer (score 0):

1. Extract the part of the method that you want to become static. Yes, this will still refer to fields.
2. Make the new method `static`.
3. In the caller, pass the fields as parameters (use the warnings about fields not being accessible from the static method as a reference).
4. `CTRL-1` the extracted method in the caller, and pick `+ Change method: Add parameter`

The extracted static method should now have parameters that hide the fields because they have the same name.